# Set up Environment and Call Correct Jupyter Path

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter, conda, hpc

I'm currently working on an hpc system where I have to need to change the default path for Jupyter that points to the correct path where my Conda environment is based out of.

The problem: When trying to run Jupyter it points to the default and I'm not able to use any of the packages set up in my own Conda environment. (e.g. pandas, sci-kit).

Question: How can I set up my Jupyter path so it points to where my Conda environment, in other words set up environment and then call the correct "/where/ever/jupyter $@" itself

Hope this was clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install ipykernel:

```
conda install -c anaconda ipykernel
```

and then:

```
python -m ipykernel install --user --name=<YOUR_CONDA_ENV>
```

after that you'll be able to select your conda environment as the jupyter kernel on the dropdown (upper right corner):

[image]